# Calculate a discount factor of 2% per year

Tags: javascript

I need to write a piece of code that requests a value for the number of years of a contract. Then use a for loop to calculate a discount factor of 2% per year, i.e. if it is a one year contract, the price will be 98% of the full price, if it is a two year contract, the price will be 96% of the full price, and so on.

I seem to be a little stuck and not sure if I have totally grasped what they are asking.

Here is what I have already done:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transition//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>
    <script type = "text/javascript">

    var stringVariable = prompt ("Enter the number of people")
    var numberVariable
    var loopCounter = prompt ("How many years?");
    var numberCount = new Array(100/2);

    if (stringVariable <= 30) {
        numberVariable = 15*stringVariable;
    }
    else if (stringVariable> 30 && stringVariable<60) {
        numberVariable = 12*stringVariable;
    }
    else if (stringVariable>60) {
        numberVariable =12*stringVariable;
    }

    alert ("Total cost is: $" + numberVariable);

    for (loopCounter = 0; loopCounter <= 4; loopCounter++)
    {
        document.write("Total discount $" + loopCounter - numberCount[loopCounter] + "<br />");
    }

    alert ("Total cost is: $" + numberVariable - numberCount);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: After two years, the price won't be 96% of the original. It will be 96.04% of the original.

Comment: Whatever you're selling, sign me up for 50 years

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems to be fundamentally flawed in a few places, especially your variable names.

Here's how I'd tackle the problem:

```
// parseInt() converts strings into numbers. 10 is the radix.
var num_people = parseInt(prompt('Enter the number of people'), 10);
var num_years = parseInt(prompt('How many years?'), 10);

// Initialize your variables.
var cost = 0;
var discount = 1.00;

// Your if condition was a bit odd. The second part of it would be
// executed no matter what, so instead of using else if, use an
// else block
if (num_people <= 30) {
  cost = 15 * num_people;
} else {
  cost = 12 * num_people;
}

alert('Total cost is: $' + cost);

// Here is a for loop. i, j, k, ... are usually
// used as the counter variables
for (var i = 0; i < num_years; i++) {
  // Multiplying by 0.98 takes 2% off of the total each time.
  discount *= 1.00 - 0.02;

  // You fill the rest of this stuff in
  document.write('Total discount $' + ... + '<br />');
}

// And this stuff
alert('Total cost is: $' + ...);
```

Comment: Good on you for posting this. BTW, why not just use `discount *= 0.98;`? :)

Comment: @Nick: I'm just explicitly showing where the `0.98` came from.